# Scroll issue with safari when doing single page websites

Tags: html, css, safari

This might be the dumbest question, but Im building a single page website, where you have to scroll down to get to the "next page".. It has one background in a fixed position div and so far Ive only implemented css and html. Havent even started the real work.. Just sort of testing the design.. how I'd like to have things.
It works just fin under Chrome and Firefox, but almost dies on Safari.
I wonder if its just my mac or theres something to the way I do things. Safari does not like overlaying divs, or what?! :(

HTML

```
<div id="background"></div>
<div id="container">
  <div id="header">Page title</div>
  <!--menu comes here later on-->
  <div id="content">CONTENT</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#background {
  position:fixed;
  top:0px; left:0px;
  width:100%; height:100%;
  background:url(bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size:cover; -moz-background-size:cover; -o-background-size:cover; background-size:cover;
}

#container {
  position:absolute;
  top:0px; left:0px;
  width:100%; height:100%;
}

#header {
  position:absolute;
  top:2%; left:7%;
  font-family:"Times New Roman";
  font-size:50px;
  color:#ffffff;
}

#content {
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  width:100%; height:1000px;
  background:#ffffff;
  box-shadow:0px -3px 25px #252525;
}
```

Any ideas?!
Thanks!

Comment: Please post images on how it look on different browsers, it will help user's not having MAC or PC.

Comment: It looks completely the same, but the scrolling lags on safari. Thats all.